# Storing/retrieving array from localstorage in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm missing something elementary in my attempt to store and retrieve an array in localstorage in my Angular 4 app.

The app retrieves the array from the server into an 'any' typed variable called aToDo as:

```
{"qoption":"Trap Surveyor (<em>Competency for CM OAP<\/em>)"}
```

and stored in localstorage by:

```
localStorage.setItem('aToDo',JSON.stringify(this.aToDo));
```

It's retrieved from localstorage as:

```
this.aToDo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('aToDo'));
```

A console.log of this.aToDo displays:

```
{"qoption":"Trap Surveyor (<em>Competency for CM OAP<\/em>)"}
```

But by this stage, things are stuffed as logging this.aToDo.qoption yields 'undefined' and the *ngFor used to list the array's contents generates the damning error:

```
Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '{"qoption":"Trap Surveyor (<em>Competency for CM OAP<\/em>)"}' of type 'string'.
```

Where is my error?  Thanks/Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. console.log will output "undefined" by default alongside your output because it's not a return function. That's normal.
2. aToDo is an object, not an array. You cannot use ngFor on an object.

Comment: Thanks for getting me on track. Finally got to the point I wanted by interating objectKeys(aToDo). Cheers/T